# Opening Docker container port on localhost in browser returns empty response

Tags: php, docker, containers, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I'm trying to run a web project from a Docker container,
when I Dockerize the application on a macBook with an intel chip, everything runs fine and I can make a call to the Docker container. But when I run the same project, with the same setup on my M2 MacBook Air, the browser returns an empty response.
("this page isn't working" --> in Chrome)

This happens even though the containers appear to be running...
(Both containers are green lit up --> in Docker Desktop)

The container makes use of an Nginx service and a php service. The .yml file looks as below:

## Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php:8.0.6-fpm
    container_name: Asset-Service
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: Asset-Service
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:stable
    container_name: Asset-Web-Server
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8087:80"
      - "4487:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

My Dockerfile is the following, even though I don't think that this file causes the problem:

## Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0.6-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    mariadb-client-10.3 \    
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    pkg-config \
    libssl-dev \    
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    nano

RUN pecl uninstall mongodb
RUN pecl install mongodb
RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mongodb.ini

# Clear cache
## RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

#RUN docker-php-ext-enable mongodb

# Install composer
## RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -fg 1000 www
RUN id -u 1000 >/dev/null 2>&1 || useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

### The container logs look normal and the ports in the inspect tab show 0.0.0.0:8087 and 0.0.0.0:4487.

Is this a recurring issue with the apple silicon version of Docker,
and is there anything I can do about it?

I have already tried to replicate the issue on an Intel macBook, but got the desired result instead of the empty response.

On my M2 I tried reinstalling Docker and rebuilding the containers but this didn't seem to fix anything...

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind this issue.
This problem occurred when trying to build the containers from the Desktop folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).